# WebBrowser Control ScreenShot

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, screenshot

I am trying to get a screenshot with c# windows form application. 
Source code link : http://4rapiddev.com/csharp/c-generate-website-screenshot-and-save-thumbnail/

I changed browser emulation with registry key. (HKLM > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Internet Explorer > Main > FeatureControl > FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION).

But still  my generated image comes up wrong, background image must be full screen (supersized).

sample url : http://www.fotografcisec.com/fotografci-adi/serkan-baydemir

[image: true_image]
[image: wrong_image]

Answer (score 0):

Your background is drawn using JavaScript. It could be that the browser control does not handle JavaScript very well. Try adding the web browser control to your form, loading that URL in the control, and see how the page renders. And maybe once it fully renders, try the DrawToBitmap again. e.g. Add a button on the page and have it do the save to bitmap after the browser control has finished rendering.